# Notepad++ find string with a new-line and replace

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, tags

**[Notepad++ Question]**

How do I use ***find-and-replace*** to replace the attribute of a series of tags using ***expression***?

**Case scenario:**

Let's say I have a couple of lines of something like this:

```
<li><a title="Bla bla" href=
    "http://www.url.com/etc">Text</a></li>
```

And I want to replace them with this:

```
<li><a title="Bla bla" href="">Text</a></li>
```

***Note the new line and double tabs on the original.***

Answer (score 4):

Speaking specifically about the newline and double-tabs, using the **Extended** Searched Mode find:

> \r\n\t\t

and replace with:

> *(blank, nothing, empty string)*

And assuming you are wanting to remove the URL from the href, leaving a blank reference, you'll want to use the **Regular expression** Search Mode to find:

> href=\"*(insert-http-url-regex-here)*\"

and replace with:

> href=\"\"

Comment: for some reason, notepad++ uses the SciTE implementation of regular expression which is a line by line search pattern. That's why this is a two step process, you can't use regular expression in Notepad++ to find line breaks.

You might want to check out Textpad if you are going to be doing this kind of work all of the time.

Comment: Sure, but as I detailed in my answer you CAN find line breaks using Extended search mode.  Is it a problem to run two steps?  And while I did use and promote Textpad for years, I switched, and the asker asked specifically about Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't use regular expression-replace over multiple lines (in Notepad++) so you have to make them one-liners first. Here is how to do that using a macro:

1. Hit <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> and enter `href=` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd>
2. Start recording a macro (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+R</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> 3 times (once for linebreak, twice for tabs)
4. Finish recording the macro (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+R</kbd> again)
5. Hit <kbd>F3</kbd> to search the next `href=` occurence.
6. Execute macro (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+P</kbd>)
7. Continue with Step 5 until all occurences are replaced.

*Note:* If all your `href=` appearences are the same, you can also put the search into the macro (i.e. switch steps 1 and 2) and execute the macro until everything is on one line.

Now you can do a search & replace with regular expressions (<kbd>CTRL+H</kbd>):
Search for: `href=".*">`
Replace with: `href="">`